I need help integrating Firebase database in Flutter project
I have a mobile application project developed with Flutter. Interfaces have already been designed and coded in the project. Now I am trying to extract data by connecting this project to the Firebase database, but I am not successful.
I downloaded the project from GitHub and tried to follow the necessary steps, but I got stuck on the step of creating the Firebase project. I don't know exactly how to create a project in the Firebase console and integrate it into the Flutter project.
You can currently access the project's GitHub repository here.
https://github.com/closemehmet/aphasia
I'm waiting for your help. Thank you from now.

You'll need to provide more information than just "I got stuck".  Please edit the question to be clear what exactly you're doing and what doesn't work the way you expect.  You might be helped by reviewing the Firebase help page on creating a project.  If you're getting an error in the console that doesn't make sense, you should reach out to Firebase support directly.
